# Java socket - lost bytes and 100% processor power consumption

Tags: java, sockets, networking, stream

Im making a simple socket app that connects with my server using through TCP. I need to read 2 byte values sometimes, so it all goes like:

```
public byte[] read(int bytes)
{
    byte b[] = new byte[bytes];
    try {
        in.read(b); //in is InputStream from properly connected Socket.getInputStream()
    return b;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This function should receieve given number of bytes and return it in array. The problem is, that sometimes it reads one byte before rest is available and returns weird data.

```
byte a[]=read(2); //Program is blocked here untill some bytes arrive...
System.out.prntln(a[0]); //always correct
System.out.prntln(a[1]); //unprintable character (probably 0 or -1)
```

My quick fix was to add while loop checking if there is enough data to read:

```
public byte[] read(int bytes)
{
    byte b[] = new byte[bytes];
    try {
        while (in.available()<bytes); //It does the thing
        in.read(b);
    return b;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But that loop is using 100% of processor power (one core, actually), which is very annoying. Is there any way to rewrite that function (param and return value must be exactly the same) so it works correctly?

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Why should I do this here, and will this do the job? I can't find any realtion between finally{} and my problem, am I wrong?

Comment: it's a comment btw you have to close your resources when you open e.g InputStreams

Comment: I close them when I don't need those InputStreams anymore. This is just a helper function. Aslo, aren't the streams auto closed when socket is?

Comment: @nachokk - it is an **irrelevant** comment.  Nothing to do with Question at hand.  Like reminding the OP to wipe his nose.

Comment: The loop uses 100% processor power because it runs madly. See you have put a `;` after the `while` statement. So it is an effective empty infinite loop.

Comment: First problem.  Look at the javadoc for InputStream.read(byte[] ) it returns the number of bytes actually read from the stream.  If that is fewer than you are expecting, then the byte array will contain zeros at the end, which might explain what you are seeing.  At the very least capture and print the number of bytes actually read.  This is a comment on the first block of code, not the quick fix.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders I know what it does and I placed it there for a reason. That was temporary fix, now Im trying to make this code better.

Comment: @Keith so I should collect those bytes untill I have whole data?

Comment: @kittyPL If you know what it does you should code accordingly. 'Temporary fix' is not the time to be writing wrong code, not that there is one, and if you know better there is really no excuse.

Comment: @EJP Actually that wasn't the most important part of my app, and this function actually was blocking very few times... I decided to leave it that way just becouse I wanted to move on with the rest. Im a human, I have some preferences what do I want to do, so I just left TODO mark and continued...

Comment: @kittyPL You post code here, it will get commented on. If it's poor code, comment will be adverse. That's SO. If you think it doesn't matter why did you post it?

Comment: @noisycat There's another problem with that `while` statement. It says, "I won't read any bytes the other side has already sent until the other side sends more of them". The problem is, TCP explicitly allows the other side's TCP stack to say, "I won't send any more bytes until the other side reads some of them". If both of those things happen, you can deadlock. So if you're sending data over TCP, you *must* *not* *ever* wait for the other side to send more data before you receive what it has already sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Your quick fix is a bad idea.  In fact, any code that uses `available` is probably broken.

Here's how I'd do this:

```
public byte[] read(int bytes) throws IOException {
    byte b[] = new byte[bytes];
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < b.length) {
       int nosRead = in.read(b, pos, b.length - pos);
       if (nosRead == -1) {
          return null;  // Not the best idea ... see below.
       } else {
          pos += nosRead;
       }
    }
    return b;
}
```

There is no need to "poll" the stream using `available()`.  There is no need to sleep.  You just make use of the fact that `read` will only return if either it has read at least one byte OR you've fit the "end of stream".

---

Note that I also don't think it is right to return a `null` if your `read` method fails.  It is better to throw an exception ... or let the `IOException` from the `in.read()` call propagate.

This applies to my rewrite as well ... I didn't want to change the behaviour of your code in that respect.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The other answer is good aswell, Is is okay for you if I accept that one (becouse Mr. C has less rep than you)? Thank you for help :)

Comment: @kittyPL - Unfortunately, if you read "Mr C" answer carefully, it has a number of mistakes.  (I'll leave it to you to figure out what the mistake in his code is ... but his advice on NIO is misguided, or at least oversimplified.)

Comment: I see now. Hope he is going to change this :)

Comment: @StephenC +1 but there is no IOException to propagate. The code should throw EOFException. Agree all your other statements.

Comment: @EJP - The `read` call can throw an `IOException`.  Try removing the `throws` clause and asking the compiler what it thinks ... :-)

Comment: There is no IOException to propagate if read() returns -1, which is the occasion for the reference in your answer.

Comment: But what if the read fails due to something *other than* EOF?  Like a `SocketException` or a `ProtocolException` or an `InterruptedIOException`?  (I can't vouch for all of those actually being possible, but at least some are plausible.)  Have you tried asking the compiler, like I suggested?

Comment: @StephenC Nobody is contesting that `read()` throws `IOException`, but you made the suggestion about propagating `IOException` in the context of read() returning -1 and what to do about it, which is a case where there hasn't yet been an `IOException` at all.

Comment: @EJP - What I actually wrote was *"...I also don't think it is right to return a null if your read method fails"*.  I was referring to the **OP's original and quick-fix code** where it catches `IOException` and returns `null`.  Please credit me with *some* intelligence ...

Comment: @StephenC, I did upvote this answer, and incidentally you might credit me with some intelligence as well, instead of assuming I don't know that `read()` throws `IOException` (and, even more bizarrely, assuming I need the assistance of a compiler to find out). Your *code* returns null *if `read()` returns -1* and under *no other circumstance.* Can I assume your comments relate to your code in some way?

Comment: The comment is saying that returning `null` is a bad idea.  And its is referring to the two sentences below that say: *"Note that I also don't think it is right to return a null if your read method fails. It is better to throw an exception ... or let the IOException propagate."*.  To which you responded that an `IOException` cannot be thrown at that point.  To which I responded, yes it can ... and gave some examples.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused by what I meant by "when your read method fails`.  There are *TWO* "failure" conditions, in this context.  1) returning -1, or 2) raising an exception.

Comment: There are (obviously) three reasons why returning `null` is a bad idea.  1) It conflates the different types of "failure" ... so that the caller won't know there was a problem, 2) it discards the evidence of the problem ... making debugging hard, and 3) it requires the caller to do a `null` test ... or risk an NPE.  I didn't bother to spell this out in detail because I thought it was tangential to the Question.  And I didn't bother to spell out that the problem (in part) was in the OP's original code and my code.

Comment: And I certainly didn't think it would be necessary to point out that `return null` doesn't either raise or propagate an exception.  And that someone wouldn't realise that (obviously) that's not what I meant.  Or that someone would even *bother* to fault me for that ...

Comment: @StephenC Why I return null in case of error: Becouse I don't care what was the problem at that moment. I just disconnect. This is a simple program, so I removed debugging code as soon as everything was working fine. I understand its important to handle every error and every single bigger project that I was writing had error handling written pretty well... Since I can't see a single reason for this particular app to handle every error (I'd probably just disconnect anyway), I decided to leave it this way.

Comment: Fair enough.  It is not a totally bad idea.  Indeed there are some std Java stream methods that work this way; e.g. `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` to signify EOF.  (And not withstanding all of the comments above ... the `null` issue is tangential to the main point of my Answer.)

Comment: So your comment doesn't relate to the code you posted. You could always clarify your post accordingly. You don't need to keep assuming other disagreements that don't exist, such as whether read() throws IOExceptions, or whether the compiler enforces it, or whether there are multiple failure modes; and I don't have any objection to returning null at EOS as long as it's clear that it can't also mean another failure condition.

Answer (score 2):

Throw it away and use DataInputStream.readFully().